# segmentation fault before execution of main

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am practicing c and facing segmentation fault before the main function executes ( "hi" isn't printing and even gdb isn't mentioning the line of error except that the call is from main function).
can some one please help me from where the error is from ? I tried figuring out and surfing for the error online but could not find anywhere for the type of code I have.

```
   #include<stdio.h>

    int main(){
        printf("hi");
        double L,dx,dy,dt;

    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf",&L,&dx,&dy,&dt);

        int i,j;
        int x=L/dx;
        int y=L/dy;
        double ar[1000][1000];
        double o1=x/2;
        double o2=y/2;
        int D=2;
        double den[1000][1000];
        double den1[1000][1000];
        //printf("hi");

        for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<y;j++)
            {
                if(i==o1 && j==o2)
                {
                ar[i][j]=1;
                den[i][j]=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ar[i][j]=0;
                    den[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        //printf("hi");
        for(i=1;i<x-2;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<y-2;j++)
            {
                den1[i][j]=den[i][j]+((den[i+1][j]-den[i][j]+den[i-1][j]-den[i][j])/dx*dx+(den[i][j+1]-den[i][j]+den[i][j-1]-den[i][j])/dy*dy
                    )*dt+((den[i+1][j]-den[i][j]+den[i-1][j]-den[i][j])/dx*dx+(den[i][j+1]-den[i][j]+den[i][j-1]-den[i][j])/dy*dy)*dt;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<y;j++)
            {
                printf("%lf",ar[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<y;j++)
            {
                printf("%lf",den1[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: _""hi" isn't printing "_ Try `printf("hi\n");`

Comment: remove the `c++` tag - you are using `C` not `C++`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local variables, including arrays, are stored on the stack. The default stack-size on Linux is 8MB. Just one single of your arrays is alone 8 million bytes, 1000 * 1000 * 8 (`sizeof(double)` is 8). You have *three* of these arrays.

Either make these arrays global, or allocate dynamically.

Comment: Hi I know this is a very old thread.  What would you recommend to catch his mind of issue?  GDB certainly says nothing about it.  Thanks!

Comment: @HCSF Stack overflows like these are almost impossible to catch. Good coding practices, static analysis tools, and code reviews go a long way to help prevent it in the first place. It's probably possible using tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Your function probably uses too much stack memory, caused by these lines:

```
double ar[1000][1000];
double den[1000][1000];
double den1[1000][1000];
```

Solution: Allocate the memory from the heap:

```
double* den = malloc( 1000 * 1000 * sizeof( double ));
etc.
```